# Observable: get unique array values from collection documents

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

What is the best way to create a list of unique values from Firestore arrays?

Each document in the collection can have any number of categories which are written in document array "categories".

I'm trying to get all unique categories of array values to populate filtering options so I need to be sure that there is a hotel for this category. I can't use just all categories list from other collection.

Angular 8, Firestore, angularfire 2, Ionic 4

Observable:

```
this.hotels = afs.collection('hotels', ref => ref.where('city_id', '==', cityId).orderBy('reviews_number', 'desc')).valueChanges();
```

Component html:

```
<li *ngFor="let hotel of hotels | async">
{{ hotel.categories }}
</li>
```

Result:

```
wifi
wifi
wifi,pool,center
pool
```

And I can't figure out what is the best practice to get unique values from arrays to be able to populate the dropdown with all unique values options.

```
wifi,pool,center
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep things cleaner, I'd suggest using a separate variable to host your dropdown values, subscribing to Firestore values and fetching out the unique values then

TYPESCRIPT:

```js
class MyComponent {
  dropDownOptions: Array<any> = [];
  someMethod() { // only called once in the component
    this.hotels = afs.collection('hotels', ref => ref.where('city_id', '==', cityId)
      .orderBy('reviews_number', 'desc'))
      .valueChanges();
    this.hotels.subscribe((hotels) => {
      const options: Array<string> = hotels.reduce((prevValue, hotel) => {
        return [...prevValue, ...hotel.categories];
      }, []);
      
      this.dropDownOptions = options.filter(this.onlyUnique); // get unique values
    })
  }

  onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  }

}
```

HTML:

```html
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let option of dropDownOptions" value="{{option}}">
    {{ option }}
  </option>
</select>
```

### UPDATE:

There was a typo in the HTML. I.e. the `dropdownOptions` should have been `dropDownOptions`. Fixed it.
Also, I've put a [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6q9xr) that demonstrates the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for help, final code should look like this: https://pastebin.com/B2nv5FAh but dropdownOptions is empty

Comment: in HTML when doing {{ dropDownOptions }} I'm getting unique values! wifi,pool,center -  it works, just *ngFor not returing values

Comment: @TedAce please check my answer (UPDATE section), I've added a stackblitz example that demonstrates the solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: Works, how I didn't check for type error :))) Maybe you know how to exclude empty values as well? As now empty value (hotel don't have any category) included as well. Thanks again

Comment: You can change `return [...prevValue, ...hotel.categories];` in the code to `return [...prevValue, ...hotel.categories.filter(category => category !== "")];` to exclude empty strings as categories.
Also, please upvote the answer and comments if they helped you :) Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, for sure.  Can you push me to right direction once again :) in Stackblitz I tested filtering for empty values - works well. But in my app, I'm getting an error in console: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined. I'm using Ionic4 Angular8

Comment: You have to make sure that the property `hotel.categories` is always an array. It cannot be undefined. In short, every hotel should have `categories` property.

Answer (score 1):

You could use RxJS's *mergeMap()* to emit single *hotel* objects, *distinct()* to filter out the duplicates based on the **id** and zip it back up into an array with
*toArray()*

```
this.hotels = afs.collection('hotels', ref => ref.where('city_id', '==', cityId)
  .orderBy('reviews_number', 'desc'))
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(mergeMap(hotels => hotels), distinct(hotel => hotel.id), toArray());
```

I have not worked with Firebase but if I had to guess, the *valueChanges()* is a never ending stream. In that case, *toArray()* would not work and you'd need to *scan()* the values and push into an *array*.

```
this.hotels = ...valueChanges().pipe(
  mergeMap(hotels => hotels), 
  distinct(hotel => hotel.id), 
  scan((acc, val) => acc.concat(...val), []));
```